# iOS WidgetKit - two dynamic Intents for one widget

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit, customintents

I have one widget and would like to have two dynamic inputs using searchbar. Is that possible? Using ios14, widgetKit.

I could create two CustomIntents and the IntentHandler has two provideOptionsCollection, like so

```
func provideIntent1Collection(for intent: Intent1, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<Selections>?, Error?) -> Void) {}
func provideIntent2Collection(for intent: Intent2, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<Selections>?, Error?) -> Void) {}
```

But how do we add IntentConfigurations for two intents in one Widget struct? And how to handle both intents in single IntentTimelineprovider.
Please let me know if this is possible. Thanks